# Jenkins: ChromeDriver update PATH from shell script and use new version

Tags: selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver

I am looking for a way to update the PATH in Jenkins for running Selenium tests with PyTest.
I need to run the latest version of `chromedriver` but due to an infrastructure deficiency (our base image is running Debian and the latest available version is `73` and I need to be running at least `83`).
There is already a version of `chromedriver` installed on the image at `/usr/bin` and I need to be able to point to a different version

The jenkins chromedriver plugin appears that it will just use the latest available version for debian, which doesn't help me at all.

Until I have time to address the systemic issue, I'd like to just install `chromedriver` and update `PATH` - because Selenium requires `chromedriver` on the `PATH`

It seemed, for ease of use, that https://pypi.org/project/chromedriver-binary/ was a good solution - it installs just fine and the shell script `chromedriver-path` echoes the location, so I could just update path as the documentation shows: `PATH=$PATH:chromedriver-path`

This doesn't seem to jive in Jenkins - `PATH` is not updated

```
stages {
    stage('build'){
        steps {
            withCredentials([...]) {

                    sh """
                        alias python=python3.8
                        python -m venv --system-site-packages venv # only for jenkins
                        python -u setup.py
                        . venv/bin/activate

                        which chromedriver #/usr/bin/chromedriver  
                        chromedriver-path #path/to/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/chromedriver_binary
                        export PATH=$PATH:`chromedriver-path`
                        
                        which chromedriver #/usr/bin/chromedriver
                        
                    """

                    sh "python -m pytest"
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

I Have looked at the `withEnv()` option and `environment{}` step but I'm not sure how to access that binary and update `PATH` once `chromedriver-binary` has been set - because it appears that `environment{}` would not have access to shell scripts that are installed in the individual steps.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated

Comment: How do you start chromedriver? Or do you use Selenium standalone server? How do you initialize connection to the browser in your tests?

Comment: @OndrejMachulda it is started in `pytest` using `webdriver.Chrome` - which reads the `PATH` to find the chromium binary

Comment: So you can't pass webdriver.Chrome the `executable_path` parameter with path to the chromedriver binary?

Comment: I guess I'd have to know where it's installed and where to pass the parameter in - what would be the best way to communicate the binary location, an argument passed in to `python ... ` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue may actually be in Jenkinsfile declaration.

Try using `sh` with single quotes `'''`. Also binaries are searched in directories defined in `PATH` from left to right, so to override system `PATH`, you must put your directory on the beginning, not on the end.

If I alter your code snippet:

```
stages {
    stage('build'){
        steps {
            withCredentials([...]) {

                    sh '''
                        alias python=python3.8
                        python -m venv --system-site-packages venv # only for jenkins
                        python -u setup.py
                        . venv/bin/activate

                        which chromedriver #/usr/bin/chromedriver  
                        chromedriver-path #path/to/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/chromedriver_binary
                        export PATH=$(chromedriver-path):$PATH
                        
                        echo $PATH # just to check the output, your path should be on the beginning
                        which chromedriver # this should now find the proper chromedriver
                        
                    '''

                    sh "python -m pytest"
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I was reading how the single quotes change the interpreter... that's frustrating, but it is setting the path now! One slight note, with `python -m pytest` in a new `sh` command, the virtual env is deactivated - so using this as it stands, I'd have to reactivate the venv - but that makes it work fine. I'm going to clean it up, however.

Comment: How you would go about adding interpolated params to `pytest`? I have the following command `python -m pytest tests/${params.TEST} --html=results/report.html -n${params.PROCESSES} --reruns=${params.RERUNS} --env=${params.ENV} --csv results/test_results.csv` but I cannot interpolate those values inside of single ticks `'`. If I open a new shell command I lose context

Comment: Thats a tricky one... I guess then you must use `withEnv` and put the values from the params into environment variables of the shell. Something like ```withEnv(["PROCESSES=${params.PROCESSES}"]) { sh''' echo $PROCESSES '''
}
```

Comment: FWIW, with some tinkering, the quotes weren't the cause at all - each subsequent `sh` command opens up a new shell, so any environment variables or configuration that you set in a previous `sh` are lost in the next. So in my above example, it would work fine if I just nested the `python pytest` command in the first `sh` command ¯\_(ツ)_/¯. That being said, I was able to replace the single ticks with double and interpolate the params just fine